# Cannot get bottom of Paragraph Box to Wrap around Floated Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to follow this Mozilla Tutorial on floats and am trying to do the exercises.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats

I have a left floated div with a Paragraph element to the right of it which has a pink background. I am trying to make the bottom of the Pink Paragraph box wrap around the bottom of the blue Div, and not stop when the text finishes, like it advises me to do in the Mozilla Tutorial. However I am not able to do it at all, and I have tried using all of the methods they have shown.

Please can somebody advise me

I have tried using

Overflow: auto;
Display: flow-root;

```css
     body { width:90%;
           margin: 0 auto;
           background: #AAB7B8;}

     .wrapper { display: flow-root;}


     .box { border: solid 1px;
           background: blue;
           border-radius: 5px;
           width: 200px;
           height: 200px;
           float: left;
           margin: 20px;
          text-align: center;
      
         }


       p {  background: #F6DDCC;
          padding:20px;}

      .cleared { clear: left;
              background: yellow;}
```

```html
          <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box">
             Float 
           </div>
          <p> Many variations of Lorem Ipsum exist today, and sometimes the 
        text is altered to include humorous phrases.
        If you’re going to be using Lorem Ipsum as filler text on your pages, 
        you need to make sure that the passage doesn’t contain potentially 
        embarrassing information.
        Using our Lorem Ipsum generator, you can easily select a variation to 
        build your desired number of Lorem Ipsum paragraphs, sentences, or 
         words.In addition, our generator can insert HTML markup. </p>
      
        <p class="cleared">  when a printer jumbled a gallery of type to 
          create a type specimen book, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry 
          standard for dummy text.

         Today, a variety of software can create random text that resembles 
         Lorem Ipsum. For example, Apple’s Pages and Keynote software use 
         scrambled placeholder text. And Lorem Ipsum is featured on Google 
         Docs, WordPress, and Microsoft Office Word.
          </p>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap `box` and the paragraph `<p>` with a `div` and set the wrapping div with the background color

```css
body { 
        width:90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #AAB7B8;
     }

     .p-wrapper{
        background: #F6DDCC;
         padding: 20px;
         display: flow-root;
     }
     .box { 
          border: solid 1px;
           background: blue;
           border-radius: 5px;
           width: 200px;
           height: 200px;
           float: left;
           margin: 20px;
          text-align: center;
      
         }


       p {  background: #F6DDCC;
          padding:20px;}

      .cleared { clear: left;
              background: yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="p-wrapper">
          <div class="box">
             Float 
           </div>
          <p> Many variations of Lorem Ipsum exist today, and sometimes the 
        text is altered to include humorous phrases.
        If you’re going to be using Lorem Ipsum as filler text on your pages, 
        you need to make sure that the passage doesn’t contain potentially 
        embarrassing information.
        Using our Lorem Ipsum generator, you can easily select a variation to 
        build your desired number of Lorem Ipsum paragraphs, sentences, or 
         words.In addition, our generator can insert HTML markup. </p>
      </div>
        <p class="cleared">  when a printer jumbled a gallery of type to 
          create a type specimen book, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry 
          standard for dummy text.

         Today, a variety of software can create random text that resembles 
         Lorem Ipsum. For example, Apple’s Pages and Keynote software use 
         scrambled placeholder text. And Lorem Ipsum is featured on Google 
         Docs, WordPress, and Microsoft Office Word.
          </p>
           </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sam for helping me with that

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly.. something like the below...

All I did was add...

```
.wrapper {  background: #F6DDCC;}
```

And removed the background color from the paragraph tag.

```
p {  padding:20px;}
```

So the background color is applied to the containing div and not the paragraph elements.

```css
body { width:90%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       background: #AAB7B8;}

 .wrapper { display: flow-root;}


 .box { border: solid 1px;
       background: blue;
       border-radius: 5px;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       float: left;
       margin: 20px;
      text-align: center;

     }


.wrapper {  background: #F6DDCC; }

p { padding:20px;}

  .cleared { clear: left;
          background: yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box">
         Float 
       </div>
      <p> Many variations of Lorem Ipsum exist today, and sometimes the 
    text is altered to include humorous phrases.
    If you’re going to be using Lorem Ipsum as filler text on your pages, 
    you need to make sure that the passage doesn’t contain potentially 
    embarrassing information.
    Using our Lorem Ipsum generator, you can easily select a variation to 
    build your desired number of Lorem Ipsum paragraphs, sentences, or 
     words.In addition, our generator can insert HTML markup. </p>

    <p class="cleared">  when a printer jumbled a gallery of type to 
      create a type specimen book, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry 
      standard for dummy text.

     Today, a variety of software can create random text that resembles 
     Lorem Ipsum. For example, Apple’s Pages and Keynote software use 
     scrambled placeholder text. And Lorem Ipsum is featured on Google 
     Docs, WordPress, and Microsoft Office Word.
      </p>
       </div>
```